# How do I start one shell script as process from another shell script

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

I want to do this from my script1.sh which is run on host

```
#!/bin/sh

# adb shell "sh /sdcard/script2.sh &"
```

script2.sh is on android device inside /sdcard/ folder.

I want script2.sh to keep running on Android. script2.sh has infinite loop.
But above command is not working. script2.sh stops as soon as script1.sh exits.

I have also tried

```
# adb shell "exec sh /sdcard/script2.sh &"
```

but this also doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

In your parent shell script, extract the pid of the child process script2.sh.
and then wait for its completion using the wait system command.

```
wait <PID>
```

Refer this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124106/shell-script-wait-for-background-command) for further details.

Comment: I don't want to wait. I want my first script to exit.

Answer (score 0):

adb shell "nohup sh /sdcard/script2.sh &"

Instead of exec you can use nohup. What nohup does is it makes your script2 as child of init process (parent of all processes) as soon as script1 exits.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
If I use nohup, command works if I execute it directly on android device
nohup sh /sdcard/script2.sh -l &

but does not work if I execute from my host machine:

adb shell "nohup sh /sdcard/script2.sh &"

I started the adb session as root(adb root), so no issue of permissions.

Comment: Not getting any error but script2.sh is supposed to keep logging data to a log file on android device which is not going to the log file.

If I execute the command directly on android device "nohup sh /sdcard/script2.sh -l &" I see data going into the log file.